# Ionic 1 - Change the order of $ionicHistory

Tags: ionic-framework, state

I have 3 states : Home, StateA and StateB. I am navigate from Home to StateA, then, I want to navigate from stateA to stateB.
My problem is that the back state is StateA but I want it to be Home.

```
       __ StateA
      |
Home -
      |__ StateB
```

I didn't find the appropriate function to do this in $ionic.history documentation. How can I do this ?

Comment: you can use ionicHistory.removeBackView(); 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/service/$ionicHistory/

Comment: Wow, thank you ! I think I am a bit blind, I didn't see that function in the documentation .. !

Comment: Kindly, mark it as correct answer so that it will help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ionicHistory.removeBackView();

Reference:
[ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/service/$ionicHistory](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/service/$ionicHistory)